# Unclear EJB bean JNDI name under Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, ejb-3.0, jndi, weblogic-10.x

I made a small example using weblogic 10.3.6 and EJB 3.0. Define SimpleService class, define weblogic-ejb-jar.xml in order to map SimpleService class to JNDI name, pack it as EJB component in EAR file and deploy on server. Deployment is successful and I can see ejb bean with name SimpleServiceBean. After that using standalone application connect to webloigc server through InitialContext with all necessary environment attributes I try to lookup that bean. I assume that it will be available under name ejb/SimpleService but can't found it under that name and only after I was looking through a JNDI tree name I found out that it available under name SimpleService#ds/base/ejb/SimpleService. Help me to understand what is going on? How should I configure ejb bean in order that it will be available under ejb/SimpleService as it described in the official weblogic manual? Or maybe it's a correct JNDI name for the EJB bean?

My classes and configs are:

**ds.base.ejb.SimpleServiceBean:**

```java
@Stateless(mappedName = "ServiceBean")
@TransactionAttribute(NEVER)
@ExcludeDefaultInterceptors
@Remote(SimpleService.class)
public class SimpleServiceBean implements SimpleService {
...
}
```

**weblogic-ejb-jar.xml**

```xml
<weblogic-ejb-jar>
    <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
        <ejb-name>ServiceBean</ejb-name>
        <jndi-name>ejb/ServiceBean</jndi-name>
        <enable-call-by-reference>True</enable-call-by-reference>
    </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

**application.xml:**

```xml
<application>
    <display-name>web-app-ear</display-name>
    <module>
        <ejb>app-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
    </module>
</application>
```

*Then try to get it from standalone:*

```java
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(env);
SimpleService simpleService = (SimpleService)          
context.lookup("SimpleService#ds/base/ejb/SimpleService");
assert simpleService != null
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a good FaQ about the global portal JNDI names on glassfish.org http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#SessionBeanGlobalJNDINameAssignment
It is best practise NOT to assign a jndi name but rely on the ones defined since EE 5 (e.g. SimpleService#ds/base/ejb/SimpleService)

If you add the jndi-name configuration to your weblogic-ejb-jar.xml you could actually make it available as ejb/ServiceBean but you also have to define it "old school" style in ejb-jar.xml. More on the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml can be found http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13719/ejb_jar_ref.htm

There is also a good overview about the dd in the orcl docs.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13719/understanding.htm#EJBPG129

Assuming, that you are working with 10.3.x server version ...

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
@Stateless(mappedName="UserFacade")
public class UserFacadeImpl {

//......
}


Properties p=new Properties();
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://localhost:7001");
InitialContext ctx=new InitialContext(p);
userFacade=(UserFacade)ctx.lookup("UserFacade#com.webservices.facade.UserFacade");
```

hope it helps.